# cross initialization error in while loop (c++ program)

Tags: c++

I am doing a lot of things wrong here. Plz help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class student {
    int rno;
    char name[15];
    float marks;

public:
    void getdata()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Roll No. : ";
        cin >> rno;

        cout << "\nEnter Name : ";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "\nEnter Marks : ";
        cin >> marks;
    };

    void writedata()
    {
        fstream input;
        input.open("stu.dat", ios::out | ios::app);
        input.write((char*)this, sizeof(student));
        input.close();
    };

    void readdata()
    {
        int temp;
        cout << "\nEnter roll no: ";
        cin >> temp;

        fstream output;
        output.open("stu.dat", ios::in);
        output.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        while (output.read((char*)this, sizeof(student))) {
            if (rno == temp) {
                cout << "\nRoll no. : " << rno
                     << "\nName : " << name
                     << "\nMarks : " << marks;
            }
            else {
                cout << "\nWrong Roll no entered";
            };
        };
    };
};

int main()
{
    student s[25];
    student* st;

    char ans = 'y', ans2 = 'y', ans3 = 'y';

    int o, i = 0, j = 0;

    do {
        cout << "\nEnter your choice\n1.Write\n2.Read";
        cin >> o;

        switch (o) {
        case 1:
            while (ans2 == 'y' || ans2 == 'Y') {    
                s[i].getdata();
                s[i].writedata();

                cout << "\nDo you want to continue?";    
                cin >> ans2;

                i++;
            };
            break;
        case 2:
            while (ans3 == 'y' || ans3 == 'Y') {
                st->readdata();
                cout << "\nDo you want to continue?";
                cin >> ans3;

                j++;
            };

            break;
        };
    } while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: format your code well. add the problem clearly.

Comment: thanks for edit, i figured out previous problem, but now i could not get it to read the data entered in the file. it will be great if anybody can help me with that. (ps, i am new to programming and stack overflow)

Comment: You could start by explaining what the program is supposed to do. Next, it would be great if you tell us exactly what part of the code fails in what way.

Comment: This program is supposed to write and read student class objects to and from a file stu.dat.

Comment: The problem now i am facing is that when i run it and write some data to the file, program can not read back from the file, it gets stuck. also compiler is showing no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All seems well until line 82:

```
 st->readdata();
```

where the variable `st` is not initialised but used.

Comment: thanx to you, i did figure it out finally.